# jest timeouts when calling a database query

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

I have a test file like this.

```
const { silBastan } = require("../database.js");
const axios = require('axios').default;

describe("authentication", () => {
  describe("when data schema is valid", () => {
    test("returns 201 response code if the user doesnt already exists", async () => {
      await silBastan();
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/register', {
        email: "my_email",
        password: "1234"
      });

      expect(response.status).toBe(201);
    });
  });
});
```

And `silBastan` is defined here like this

```
const pg = require("pg");

const client = new pg.Client();
async function silBastan() {
  return await client.query(`DELETE FROM account`);
}
```

Of course i made sure the server started and connected to the database before running the tests.
I wondered if there is something wrong with `silBastan` and tested it inside a express route handler like this

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  await silBastan();
  try {
    await db.createAccount(email, password);
    res.sendStatus(201);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ err: "Already exists" });
  }
});
```

and there was no timeout. And after this i returned another promise from `silBastan` like this:

```
async function silBastan() {
  // return await client.query(`DELETE FROM account`);
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000));
}
```

And again there is no timeout. I tried couple of other variations as well like these:

```
function silBastan() {
  return client.query(`DELETE FROM account`);
}
```

```
async function silBastan() {
  await client.query(`DELETE FROM account`);
}
```

Nothing worked i always get this message:

```
 thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

I don't think the problem is with the function because i would get the same behavior in the route handler too.